# If list object contains something remove from list

Tags: python, list

I have a python script that checks a certain folder for new files and then copies the new files to another directory. The files are in such a format 1234.txt and 1234_status.txt. It should only move 1234.txt and leave the 1234_status.txt unattended.

Here's a little piece of my code in python

```
    while 1:
#retrieves listdir
        after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
#if after has more files than before, then it adds the new files to an array "added"
        added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
```

My idea is that after it fills added, then it checks it for values that have status in it and pops it from the array. Couldn't find a way to do this though : /

Comment: Have a look at [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
added = [f for f in after if not f in before and '_status' not in f]
```

I do however recommend to refrain from long one line statements as they make the code almost impossible to read

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly:

```
while 1:
    for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch):
        if 'status' not in f: # or a more appropriate condition
            move_file_to_another_directory(f)
    # wait
```

or check [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) if using Linux to avoid useless checks.

Comment: How about `if f not in before and 'status' not in f` to meet both his conditions?

Comment: @agf - what is `before`? If I really move all concerned files to another directory each time I encounter them, I won't get them with the next `os.listdir` call. Or am I missing something?

Comment: He wants to first take a list of the files in a directory, then watch the directory and move __new files__ to another directory, if I understand his question right.

Comment: before is the previous listdir, then it compares it to after(listdir at the moment) and after it does everything before=after

Answer (score 1):

```
files_in_directory = [filename for filename in os.listdir(directory_name)]
files_to_move = filter(lambda filename: '_status' not in filename, files_in_directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set logic since order doesn't matter here:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def is_status_file(filename):
    return filename.endswith('_status.txt')
# ...
added = set(after) - set(before)
without_status = filterfalse(is_status_file, added)
```